# Django how to fetch related objects with a join?

Tags: django, django-models

My `models` are similar to the following:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    def gold_star(self):
        return self.article_set.get().total_views >= 100000

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_views = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
```

Then in one of the `templates` I have this line:

```
{% if r.gold_star %}<img src="{% static 'gold-star.png' %}">{% endif %}
```

Obviously `django` sends as many queries as there are reporters on the page... Ideally this could be just one query, which would select reporters by criteria and `join` appropriate articles. Is there a way?

***EDIT***

Neither `select_related` nor `prefetch_related` doesn't seem to work as I'm selecting on the `Reporter` table and then use `RelatedManager` to access related data on the `Article`.

In other words `django` doesn't know what to prefetch until there's non empty `queryset`.

Because an article can only have one reporter it's for sure possible to join these tables together and then apply filter to subquery, I just can't find how it's done in `django` query language.

There's alternative - select on the `Article` table and filter by `Reporter` fields, but there's a problem with such approach. If I deleted all the articles of some reporter then I wouldn't be able to include that reporter in the list as from the `Article` point of view such reporter doesn't exist and yet reporter is in the `Reporter` table.

***EDIT2***

I tried what people suggested in the comments. The following generates desired query:

```
reporters = Reporter.objects.filter(**query).select_related().annotate(
    gold_star=Case(
        When(article__total_views__gte=0, then=Value(1)), 
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

Query generated by `django`:

```
SELECT 
    `portal_reporter`.`id`,
    ...,
    CASE WHEN `portal_article`.`total_views` >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `gold_star`
FROM
    `portal_reporter`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `portal_article`
ON (`portal_reporter`.`id` = `portal_article`.`reporter_id`)
WHERE
    ...
```

Now I just need to work out a way how to produce similar query but without `Case`/`When` statements.

***EDIT3***

If I chose slightly different strategy, then `django` selects wrong join type:

```
query['article__id__gte'] = 0
reporters = Reporter.objects.filter(**query).select_related()
```

This code produce similar query but with the `INNER JOIN` instead of desired `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    `portal_reporter`.`id`,
    ...,
FROM
    `portal_reporter`
INNER JOIN `portal_article`
ON (`portal_reporter`.`id` = `portal_article`.`reporter_id`)
WHERE
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try annotating the new field `gold_star` and set it to 1 if reporter has an article that has more than 100000 `total_views` like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField

reporters = Reporter.objects.annotate(
    gold_star=Case(
        When(article__total_views__gte=100000, then=Value(1)), 
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

You can leave the template code as it is.

Comment: When used together with the `select_related()` your method indeed creates appropriate join and `django` sends just one query to the db, hooray! Anyway, I would like simply join these two tables, thus without `CASE WHEN` statement. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You make join by using double underscore. You could simply write this: `reporters = Reporter.objects.filter(article__total_views__gte=100000)`

Comment: Can I use something like: `filter(article__reporter=Reporter.id)`? I get `... not 'DeferredAttribute'` error.

Comment: You can't do that, you must have an integer or instance of `Reporter` instead of `Reporter.id`, but even that doesn't make sense. What do you want exactly?

Comment: please see ***EDIT2***

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select_related` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to do a join on the related table.

There's also `prefetch_related` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which uses an `IN` clause to fetch the related objects with an extra query. The difference is explained in the docs, but is reproduced below:

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related. It also supports prefetching of GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey, however, it must be restricted to a homogeneous set of results. For example, prefetching objects referenced by a GenericForeignKey is only supported if the query is restricted to one ContentType.